# showing select instance by instance name Grails

Tags: select, grails, combobox

Hi I am allowing a user to select an already created instance of a domain but instead of the comboBox showing:

```
 com.web.service.Sand : 1
```

I would like it to display a String that the Sand domain has called name.
My current select looks like:

```
 <g:select id="sand" name="sand.id" from="${com.web.service.Sand.list()}" optionKey="id" required="" value="${productInstance?.sand?.id}" class="many-to-one"/>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement a toString() method in your domain class and have it return the name field.

```
String toString(){ name }
```

Or you can add the "optionValue" attribute to your g:select tag.

```
<g:select id="sand" name="sand.id" from="${com.web.service.Sand.list()}" optionKey="id" required="" value="${productInstance?.sand?.id}" class="many-to-one" optionValue="name" />
```